# PHP: Get content inside HTML tags and INSERT to table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following list with comments inside the **< span >** tags **< / span >**

How can I save each comment into my table?

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>
       <span>Comment 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
       <span>Comment 2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
       <span>Comment 3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to save it to my table like this:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  time  |   comment  |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  |  12:05 |  Comment 1 |
+----+--------+------------+
| 2  |  14:20 |  Comment 2 |
+----+--------+------------+
| 3  |  17:41 |  Comment 3 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

My current PHP code:

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","daniel","password","comments_db");

  $time = time();

  // $comments = ??????;

  foreach($comments as $comment) {
      mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('".$time."', '".$comment."')");
  }
?>
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: How are the comments generated? On what action do you need to make the insert happen?

Comment: If you're trying to parse HTML in PHP there's [an answer for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: @asprin Comments are generated using an input dinamically, once the user is done adding comments I'd like to submit each comment in the span element using a single submit button

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I'm actually using a PHP framework called Laravel. I just wanted to represent the query to get the idea how to retrieve each comment in the span tag element

Comment: If you're using Laravel, which is great, I'd hope you're using the database framework that comes with it. `mysqli` is awfully primitive in comparison.

Comment: @tadman Yes I'm using the database framework as well, not mysqli :) But still, that wasn't the question at all :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to get only one comment every time, the user will submit the comment to your server and you will save it.

- You can use HTML forms for posting data to the server ( [PHP 5 Form
  Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) )
- You also need to prevent sql injection ( [Prevent
  SQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) )